# How to retrieve usb information in python

Tags: python, usb

How to get the USB information like `Manufacture Name`, `Size` etc?
I am using `Ubuntu 16`.
and Python 2.7.12

Comment: `$ lsusb` gives you some information. why the `python` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this :

```
busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
   devices = bus.devices
   for dev in devices:
       print (repr(dev))
       print("manufacturer", dev.iManufacturer)
       print("Size", dev.iSize)
```

NOTE : I think it will work only when you are connected one usb at a time

Comment: I got error while executing below code

import usb
busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
   devices = bus.devices
   for dev in devices:
       print (repr(dev))
       print("manufacturer", dev.iManufacturer)
       print("Size", dev.iSize) 



Error:-

<usb.legacy.Device object at 0x7fa38112c0d0>
('manufacturer', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getusbinfo.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("Size", dev.iSize) 
AttributeError: 'Device' object has no attribute 'iSize'

Comment: Can you just refer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494086/retrieve-usb-information-using-pyudev-with-device-name  .... there capacity is just mean to size.

Comment: how to get the usb info using by pyusb

Comment: you can use `import usb.core
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)`  to  find USB devices. But I'am not sure about it can give result of size . For more : https://www.orangecoat.com/how-to/use-pyusb-to-find-vendor-and-product-ids-for-usb-devices

Comment: So I think you can try using pyudev like the answer in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494086/retrieve-usb-information-using-pyudev-with-device-name).

Answer (score 0):

with this you can print all *USB String Descriptors* in `pyusb`  : *Manufacturer String Descriptor*, *Product String Descriptor*, *Serial Number String Descriptor* ( for all USB devices, including the host controllers ) cf https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/usb.chm/usb5.htm

```
import usb

busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:

        manufacturer = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, dev.dev.iManufacturer)
        print str(manufacturer)
        product = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, dev.dev.iProduct)
        print str(product)
        serialnumber = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, dev.dev.iSerialNumber)
        print str(serialnumber)
        print('\n')
```

you have to call this as root / with `sudo` else you get  `ValueError: The device has no langid` error

other USB attributes you can print with their names :

```
import usb

busses = usb.busses()
for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:

        print "  Device class:",dev.dev.bDeviceClass
        print "  Device sub class:",dev.dev.bDeviceSubClass
        print "  Device protocol:",dev.dev.bDeviceProtocol
```