# How to get the capacity of a usb pendrive?

Tags: python-3.x, usb, pyusb, pyudev

I need to get the capacity of a usb pendrive that is unmounted. I'm using pyudev to detect it, but I don't know how to get the capacity. I read some documentation about pyusb, but I haven't found anything of useful. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve USB information using pyudev with device name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494086/retrieve-usb-information-using-pyudev-with-device-name)

Comment: No, but maybe I found something on github.  [here](https://github.com/mlf-core/system-intelligence/blob/4704382fc291418887d27cac676ecbc29e2a67cf/system_intelligence/hdd_info.py)

Comment: The answer to the linked question includes code to retrieve, among other things, the capacity of the device via the properties call.

Comment: yes I see, but it uses subprocess and I don't want use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code taken from [here](https://github.com/mlf-core/system-intelligence/blob/4704382fc291418887d27cac676ecbc29e2a67cf/system_intelligence/hdd_info.py) works pretty well:

```
def query_hdd_model() -> t.Dict[str, dict]:
    """Get information about all hard drives."""
    if not HDD:
        return {}
    context = pyudev.Context()
    hdds = {}
    for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='disk'):
        if any(_ in device.device_path for _ in IGNORED_DEVICE_PATHS):
            continue
        hdd = {'size': device.attributes.asint('size')}
        for device_ in itertools.chain([device], device.ancestors):
            try:
                hdd['model'] = device_.attributes.asstring('model')
                break
            except KeyError:
                hdd['model'] = ''
        hdds[device.device_node] = hdd
```

the exact line is the following:

```
    hdd = {'size': device.attributes.asint('size')}
```